# Java POJO Setter function is updating the value for all indices in the list

Tags: java

I have been writing piece of code where after validating the values in specific list and based upon some internal application checks to update the list value by using the loop . However in this process during first loop attempt , values at all indices in the list are getting updated . Below is the code. Could some one please help me why it is updating for all indices during first iteration but not for first index only during first iteration?

```
public class Xlist {
    private String parm1;
    private String param2;

    public String getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }

    public void setParam1(String param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;
    }

    public String param2;
    }

    public Void setParam2(String param2) {
        this.param2 = param2;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    Xlist xlist =[{1,Alpha},{2,Beta},{3,Gamma}],
    for(int i=0;i<xlist.size();i++){
        if(i==0){
            logger.info("Working on fixing the bug which is updating all the list values in single shot. Looking for values before first update");
            logger.info("Value at 1"+":"+xlist.get(0).getParam2());
            logger.info("Value at 2"+":"+xlist.get(1).getParam2());
            logger.info("Value at 3"+":"+xlist.get(2).getParam2());
        }
        xlist.get(i).setParam2("Hello"+String.valueof(xlist.get(i).getParam2()));
        if(i==0){
            logger.info("Working on fixing the bug which is updating all the list values in single shot. Looking for values after first update");
            logger.info("Value at 1"+":"+xlist.get(0).getParam2());
            logger.info("Value at 2"+":"+xlist.get(1).getParam2());
            logger.info("Value at 3"+":"+xlist.get(2).getParam2());
        }
    }
```

Output is as below:

Working on fixing the bug which is updating all the list values in single shot. Looking for values before first update

```
Value at 1: Alpha
Value at 2: Beta
Value at 3: Gamma
```

Working on fixing the bug which is updating all the list values in single shot. Looking for values after first update

```
Value at 1: Hello Alpha
Value at 2: Hello Alpha
Value at 3: Hello Alpha
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at your code:

You are doing and inside of this you are doing the update + trying to print all 3 values, but you are only updating ONCE.

```
if (i==0) {

}
```

Get rid of if (i==0){} from all places  and change your print statements and set statements to use (i) instead do:

```
logger.info("Value at " + i +":"+xlist.get(i).getParam2());
               xlist.get(i).setParam2("Hello"+String.valueof(xlist.get(i).getParam2()));
```

Comment: Text indented with 4 spaces empty lines above and  below will give code style

Comment: sorry I will try to get better at it :)

Comment: Sorry I think I did not make you understand my question. I am using i==0 condition to print check the values at all indices before setParam2() and after setParam2() during first iteration. After setParam2 in the first loop iteration, all the three values are getting updated with  xlist.get(i).setParam2("Hello"+String.valueof(xlist.get(i).getParam2()));

Comment: I dont understand your requirements @V3nky.  Are you trying to update everything at once?

Update your question to what exactl you need.

Comment: Updated my question. Problem is during the first iteration of loop, setter function is updating the values for indices but not for first index alone .As per the logic xlist.get(i).setParam2("Hello"+String.valueof(xlist.get(i).getParam2())); , it has to update the value at index passed , but it is updating all the index values from 0-2 indices.

Comment: Your existing code should give you compilation errors everywhere.

Comment: Could you please tell me on what basis you are getting compilation errors ?

Comment: @V3nky  Please paste your code into any IDE and you will see.  Example:    Getters should not be void if they return something..... public void getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224522/discussion-between-v3nky-and-susan-mustafa).